# Windows Terminal Preview - Scrolls through tabs?

Tags: windows-terminal

I recently downloaded the new Windows Terminal Preview, mainly for the tabs feature! However, when I had a lot of tabs open, I can't seem to find a way to scroll through the tabs when they start to go off the screen without closing out of other tabs first.

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Under Linux, in gnome-terminal, you can 'scroll' through the tabs with the mouse-wheel; position it on a tab and start wheeling. It might work for you as well -- you might want to try it.

Comment: @Roadowl Thanks so much! You can post as an answer if you want. I was on a laptop where I never used scrolling with the touch pad. Had to look up how to do it on my laptop but it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Linux, in gnome-terminal, you can 'scroll' through the tabs with the mouse-wheel; position it on a tab and start wheeling. It might work for you as well -- you might want to try it.